# Spree default data - multiple versions of each 'option value'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I've checked three default spree stores (the official online demo, and two installations on my localhost, using a postgres db), and this issue is present in all three. I'm using spree 2.0.4, just a default install with sample and seed data - ie, just running:

```
spree install --auto-accept
```

Under Products -> Option Types, there are multiple occurrences of each 'option value'. For example, in the tshirt-size option type, each of the values, Small up to Extra Large, appears 7 times.

Likewise, with the 'tshirt-color' option type, each of the values (red, green, blue) appears 7 times. See screenshot below.

Is this a bug? Do other people get the same result? Or is this intentional? And if it's intentional, what is the reason for it? I would have thought each 'option value' should only occur once.

[image]

Comment: I get the same result.  I believe this is a bug.  You should file an issue on the spree project: https://github.com/spree/spree/issues?state=open

Comment: done: https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/3564